# How to copy data from Sheet1 Row 1 into Sheet2 Row2 and loop through entire sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have following scenario:
I have one excel sheet with below data:
Excel Sheet 1 contains below data:

```
COLUMN 1    COLUMN 2    COLUMN 3    COLUMN 4    COLUMN 5    COLUMN 6    COLUMN 7
First Name  Last Name   Email       Phone       City        State       Zip
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
John        Adams       JA@gmail.com    1234567     Any Town    VA      12345
John        William     JW@gmail.com    1234568     Any Town    VA      12345
John        Smith       JW@gmail.com    1234569     Any Town    VA      12345
John        Edwards     JE@gmail.com    1234560     Any Town    VA      12345

================================

Excel Sheet 2

COLUMN 1    COLUMN 2        COLUMN 3    COLUMN 4
-------------------     -------------   -------------
JADAMS      JWILLIAM        JSMITH      JEDWARDS
{FIRST_NAME}{FIRST_NAME}    {FIRST_NAME}{FIRST_NAME}
{LAST_NAME} {LAST_NAME}     {LAST_NAME} {LAST_NAME}
{EMAIL}     {EMAIL}         {EMAIL}     {EMAIL}
{PHONE}     {PHONE}         {PHONE}     {PHONE}
{CITY}      {CITY}          {CITY}      {CITY}
{STATE}     {STATE}         {STATE}     {STATE}
{ZIP}       {ZIP}           {ZIP}       {ZIP}
1/1/2000    1/1/2002        1/1/2005    1/1/2000
ADD         UPDATE          INSERT      ADD
HOME        BUSINESS        HOME        BUSINESS
Y           N               Y           Y
Y           Y               N           Y
N           Y               Y           Y
M           M               M           F
```

I want to copy First Name from Sheet 1 into Sheet 2 and replace {FIRST_NAME} and other data enclosed in {} and then loop through sheet 1 until all rows are scanned.

Comment: You can use a helper column in Sheet1 that is the concatenation of the first letter of the first name and the last name.  Then do an INDEX/MATCH formula to get the proper information.

Comment: Can you copy and paste special --> paste as transpose here?

Comment: Copying Sheet1 into Sheet 2 using Transpose allowed me to then use it via =VALUE function and copy the cell data from sheet1 into cell data of Sheet2 where needed.
Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need VBA here, just copy all of your data in Sheet1, and then go to Sheet2 and `Paste Special` be sure to select the `Transpose` option

Note, to bring up the paste special dialog box you can press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>

Comment: Copying Sheet1 into Sheet 2 using Transpose allowed me to then use it via =VALUE function and copy the cell data from sheet1 into cell data of Sheet2 where needed.
Thank you CallumDA33, Scott, Matt

Comment: No problem, if this answered your question please mark it as accepted to close the question. You can do this by clicking the tick mark to the left of this answer